# Understanding why in this case $\det A = \det A'$, and more importantly why two separate $A$ and $A'$ exist

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, definition

In my linear algebra class we have learnt that each Linear Transformation $T:V \rightarrow V$ where $\dim V$ is finite has a square matrix associated with it (it is clear to that the action of matrix multiplication is equivalent to performing the linear transformation, and I know how to obtain that matrix when the transformation is provided). Similarly, we have gone on to define other notions such as the determinant of any linear transformation.

However, we have recently started the topic of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors and we have obtained this new result:

> If we have a linear transformation $\hat{A}:V\rightarrow V$ and the matrices of that linear transformation which are obtained using two separate bases say $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B'}$ are $A$ and $A'$ respectively, then $\det A = \det A'$.

This statement is alien to me, because until now I was operating under the assumption that there is only one matrix associated to each linear transformation. This, however, implies that there is more than one and that the obtained matrix depends on the choice of basis of our vector space.

I am having difficulty wrapping my head around this concept. How is this the case? Trying out a few examples using the different bases always results in the same matrix.

Is there an explanation/example for why and how this is true?

Comment: I think you should show us one of your examples where different bases result in the same matrix (as this is a pretty rare phenomenon).

Comment: Try looking up the meaning of similar matrices. That should provide a suitable explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as *the* matrix of a linear map. If you have a linear map $f\colon V\longrightarrow V$ and if $B=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then the matrix of $f$ *with respect to* $B$ is defined as follows: for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ you write $f(v_i)$ as $a_{1i}e_1+a_{2i}e_2+\cdots+a_{ni}e_n$ and then that matrix will be$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{in}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}.$$

If, for instance, $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $f(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$, then the matrix of $f$ with respect to $B=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ will be$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix},$$since$$f(1,0)=(1,1)=1\times(1,0)+1\times(0,1)$$and$$f(0,1)=(1,-1)=1\times(1,0)+(-1)\times(0,1).$$But the matrix of $f$ with respect to $B'=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\1&0\end{bmatrix},$$since$$f(1,0)=(1,1)=0\times(1,0)+1\times(1,1)$$and$$f(1,1)=(2,0)=2\times(1,0)+0\times(1,1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the transformation $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ that doubles the $x$-coordinate and leaves the $y$-coordinate unchanged. This can be shown to be linear, and the matrix of $T$ with respect to the usual basis of $\{\vec e_1,\vec e_2\}=\{(1,0)^\dagger,(0,1)^\dagger\}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$ This is because $T(\vec e_1)=2\vec e_1+0\vec e_2,$ and $T(\vec e_2)=0\vec e_1+1\vec e_2,$ which gives us the columns of the matrix.

On the other hand, we could take $\{\vec e_1,\vec e\}=\{(1,0)^\dagger,(1,1)^\dagger\}$ as a basis, instead. In that case, $T(\vec e_1)=2\vec e_1+0\vec e$ and $T(\vec e)=(2,1)^\dagger=1\vec e_1+1\vec e.$ Thus, the matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$ instead. However, you should clearly see that the determinant of both of these matrices is $2.$

The reason this happens is that for any two bases $B$ and $B'$ and any linear transformation $T$ with matrices $A$ and $A'$ (with respect to the bases $B$ and $B',$ respectively), there is an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $A'=Q^{-1}AQ.$ Hence, $$\begin{eqnarray}\det(A') & = & \det(Q^{-1})\det(A)\det(Q)\\ & = & \det(Q^{-1})\det(Q)\det(A)\\ & = & \det(Q^{-1}Q)\det(A)\\ & = & \det(I)\det(A)\\ & = & \det(A).\end{eqnarray}$$

If I recall correctly, the only transformations with unique associated matrices are scalar multiplication maps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. Do you mean this? Namely, that if $T_A$ is the matrix for $T$ with respect to the basis $A$ and if $B$ is the change of basis matrix $A\to A'$ then $T_{A'}=B^{-1}T_AB$, so $\det T_{A'}=\det T.$